# Adobe Analytics Python API

Tags: python-3.x, sdk, adobe-analytics

I am trying to return page hits for the last month.  I am using a Python Sdk that can be found  [HERE](https://github.com/dancingcactus/python-omniture)

I am using the code below:

```
report = suite.report.element("evar3").run()
```

It is only returning the top 10. How can I get to provide the full list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as the Adobe API request itself, you need to specify the [`top`](https://marketing.adobe.com/developer/documentation/analytics-reporting-1-4/r-reportdescriptionelement) property.

I'm not familiar with that python-sdk library you linked or even python in general so this is just an educated guess, but looking at the documentation you linked, looks like you should be able to do the following:

`report = suite.report.element("evar3",top=10).run()`